# Set CSS container height to lowest common height of child columns

Tags: css, css-float

How by means of only css set container height to the height of the shortest colum to avoid white space gaps? The colums are emulated (display: table* or float columns)

```
╔═════════════╤══════════════╤═════════════╗
║ ┌─────────┐ │ Shortest col │ ┌─────────┐ ║
║ └─────────┘ │ defines      │ └─────────┘ ║
║ ┌─────────┐ │ container    │ ┌─────────┐ ║
║ └─────────┘ │ height       │ └─────────┘ ║
║ ┌─────────┐ │ ┌─────────┐  │ ┌─────────┐ ║
║ └─────────┘ │ └─────────┘  │ └─────────┘ ║
║ ┌─────────┐ │ ┌─────────┐  │ ┌─────────┐ ║
║ └─────────┘ │ └─────────┘  │ └─────────┘ ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════════╝
│ ┌─────────┐ │              │ ┌─────────┐ │
│ └─────────┘ │              │ └─────────┘ │
└─────────────┘              │ ┌─────────┐ │
                             │ └─────────┘ │
                             │ ┌─────────┐ │
                             │ └─────────┘ │
                             └─────────────┘
```

Update: looking for css-only solution

Comment: I think my question is pretty legit and useful. Downwoter should at least provide comment backing their downvote.

Comment: did you look at my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

I know you don't mention `jQuery` in your post, neither in the tags, but this is a solution.

You can do a function to get each col's height, save the smaller value and set it to the container.

I set overflow-y visible so you can see how the js

```js
setheight();

function setheight(){
 $('.container').css('height', getminheight()+'px');
}

function getminheight(){
 var col = $('.container > .col'),
    height;
  $(col).each(function(){
   height = $(this).height() > height ? height : $(this).height();
  });
  return height;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  background: #ef4375;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  float: left;
}

.container .col {
  width: 33.3%;
  float: left;
}

.container .col:nth-child(1){
  background: #97b344;
  height: 150px;
}

.container .col:nth-child(2){
  background: #febb39;
  height: 100px;
}

.container .col:nth-child(3){
  background: #33a1ba;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: using JS is obvious but I am looking for css-only option

Comment: given you understood question and your solution works I upvoted it.

Comment: @user3473252 I don't know if there is a CSS-only solution, maybe there is. I will think. PS: +1 :)